# How to implement the http chunked feature in netty 4

Tags: netty

I'm upgrading some of my http client code from netty3 to netty4.

In netty3, it is every easy for me to enable or disable the chunked feature by calling the setChunked method of HttpRequest.

It's look like I have to deal the HttpContent message myself if I want to enable or disable the Chunked feature in netty4.

Is there any thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator, we can always get the Aggregated FullHttpRequest, just like we do in Netty3.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid: Yes. Netty 4 refactor a lot about Http Chunk.